# @Input with router.navigate angular4

Tags: angular, url-routing

How do you pass a value to @Input via router.navigate in an angular 4 environment?
Inline works fine:

```
<app-clinicdetail [clinicCode]="detailclinic"></app-clinicdetail>
```

but what I want is

```
this.router.navigate(['/clinicdetail'])
```

with value passing.

Comment: You *don't* pass to `@Input` by routing. If you want to pass data when routing, it goes via router parameters.

Comment: Check this documentation on how to send extra properties via navigation through the component.https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: That would expose your data in the URL none the less, if that suits your needs it's ok, you would have to use a custom service otherwise to store and retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way how you can pass params using **navigate** to the component loading by the route.

The way Angular 4 creates URL and routes is something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoadServers(id: number){
    this.router.navigate(['/servers', id, 'edit'],{queryParams: {allowEdit: '1'}, fragment: 'loading'});
  }

}
```

Due to the command **navigate** in *onLoadServers()* you will receive the following view of the route:

> http://localhost:4200/servers/1/edit?allowEdit=1#loading

In the component loading by this route you can **receive** the query params and the fragment(**loading** - in this case) with:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);//{allowEdit:"1"}
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.fragment);//loading
}
```